Sending long JWT tokens in a HTTP request in sim7600
I am using sim7600 module to make a GET request to a HTTPs site. The endpoint requires Tokens for authentication. The token is sent via HTTP parameters with the following AT command.
AT+HTTPPARA="USERDATA","Token:eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsI"\r\n
The actual tokens are much longer in length ~900 characters.
When I try to send such long characters I receive an ERROR response. I only receive an OK response when the total length of Token:eyJhb....  is <= 512.
While there is no limit mentioned in the official doc of sim7600 here it confirms that the max length is 512 for a simcom 5G module.
How can I overcome this problem other than reducing the token length?
Regards

...why can't you make HTTPS requests using TCP/IP + TLS? Why are you using AT commands? This makes no sense to me - though apparently it is a thing. Can you explain why you're doing this?

I have a sim7600 connected to an STM32 via Uart. There are no other options other than using AT commands that i know of. I have nothing to do with ESP-AT. I just want to make an http get with a large token in the header. Hope that makes it clear.
